# Detect and redirect device and OS

Tags: php, android, ios, windows, macos

I want to detect windows, mac os x, andorid ios and windows phone and redirect to relevant page using javascript or php.
I am trying to use a device and OS detection script  with this mobile detect js plugin https://github.com/hgoebl/mobile-detect.js but i don't know how to detect windows and mac desktop users.

```
function deviceDetectionScript() {

var md = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent);

if (md.mobile() && md.phone() && md.tablet()) {

    If(ios) {

        //do something

    }
    If(android) {

        //do something

    }
    If(windows) {

        //do something

    }
If(macOSX) {

        //if mac OS X (desktop)

    }
If(windows) {

        //windows desktop users

    }



} else {

    // do something else
}
```

}

Thanks